# How to detect disconnect event on a channel with Faye

Tags: ruby-on-rails, faye

I am trying to make a chat on my website looking like google talk. I
want to manage the disconnect event. A user can disconnect on several
way :

- By clicking the disconnect button (easy to push the event to his
  friends)
- By close his windows (I can send the event to windows close
  javascript event but if the user has many windows open on my website,
  i don't want to disconnect him.)

So, how can i detect when my connection on a channel is closed? Each
user has his own channel build with his id.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 5):

You can check out the meta events, `/meta/unsubscribe` and `/meta/disconnect`.

More info here: [Faye Monitoring](http://faye.jcoglan.com/ruby/monitoring.html)